# Powershell: Kill parents not child?

Tags: powershell, browser, cmd.exe

I start by clicking an icon to run a CMD batch file. (black CMD window) That opens a powershell script. In turn, that starts a second script that opens a GUI. The user makes a selection in the GUI, and a browser window opens.

However, once the browser opens, it leaves the CMD open (might be able to 'kill' that by removing the CMD/k that's in the batch file to enable error cheking). But can I 'kill' the GUI once the browser has opened?

I am currently  using "Start-Process" to open the GUI, and then another "Start-Process" in second script to open the browser. Since I believe it's 'single thread', I'm thinking that each process has got to wait for it's 'child' to finish before it can close itself, whereas ideally I would like CMD / Powershell to exit once browsers have opened.

** I have not posted code as so far it is over 300 lines.

+++++
My thanks to "HarryMC" for giving me a few pointers. I added his "Start" suggestion to the batch file, which then proceeded to close the CMD window ... but instead opened a Powershell window+GUI. Eventually, found you can hide the PS window, so the complete line was:

```
Start PowerShell -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'"
```

It does mean I get two windows flashing up on screen before the GUI loads, but getting there. Of couse, hiding the window does not mean the process has terminated - next bit of research - but (so far) looks "neater" for the end user.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening your programs in a way that each one is the child of its
parent.
To be able to let the parent terminate, you need to launch each program
as an independent process.

For CMD, the command is [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).
For PowerShell, use the
[Call operator &](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-).

Each program should call the next one, then terminate itself, which is simpler
than killing it. CMD and PowerShell will terminate automatically if invoked
to execute a single command (`cmd /c command` and `powershell "command"`).

Comment: Will have to check the "start" link, but this is what my bat reads: @ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%start.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";
echo %PowerShellScriptPath%;
rem cmd /k

At present, can't see where "start" fits.

I did use "&", but it gave me "script not found" (poss before I found the error  in pathname, so will try it again.

If "&" works, do I then add "exit" on the next line?

Comment: Another thing I saw was -Passthru, and to monitor that for when the child was closed ... but that still doesn't help situation. (The top-right X is also disabled, so got to include "cancel handler??) When I close the CMD with others still running, it (rightfully ?) throws an exception error

Comment: Better edit the script into the post, it's hard to read.